# Only last query returns results from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am querying a MySQL database through PHP.
I read input from a file. Then loop over the inputs to query the database to retrieve 3 attributes for each input.

The database connection is fine. All the queries run fine otherwise.
What is happening is for all the queries but the last one I get `mysql_num_rows($result) = 0`. And only for the last one it prints correct results.

I cannot figure out why. What might possibly be wrong?

```
$fh = fopen($my_File, 'r');
$arr = explode("\n", fread($fh, filesize($my_File)));
fclose($fh);
foreach ($arr as $line) {     
    if ($line != "\n" || $line != "" || $line != NULL) {
    $query = "SELECT id, name, status FROM table1 WHERE id='$line'";   
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if (!$result) {
        die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    $num = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if ($num == 0) {
       echo "NULL Set<br/>";       
    } else {
       echo "RESULT Set<br/>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible that the lines in your file are terminated by "\r\n" rather than just "\n"?  If so, you'll have an extra "\r" at the end of each element of $arr (except the last).

Try adding

```
$line = trim($line);
```

at the beginning of your foreach loop and see if it makes a difference.

Better yet, use [fgets](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php) instead of fread.